# I can only query with primary keys in GraphQL on Appync?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

This problem is boggling my mind.

I'm trying to query an RDS table with a non-primary key inside a graphql query.

Here is the example of two of my queries in appsync

```
query getloc{
  getLocationByCounty(County: "County"){
    LocationsID
    State
    County
  }
}
```

```
query getLocations{
  getLocation(LocationsID: 1){
    LocationsID
    State
    County
  }
}
```

The second query here works, and returns exactly the county with that LocationID.
The first returns the error message: "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'Int' within parent 'Locations' (/getLocationByCounty/LocationsID)"

If I change the schema for locations and make LocationsID non-nullable the error goes away, but it
returns null.

```
{
  "data": {
    "getLocationByCounty": {
      "State": null
    }
  }
}
```

My request resolver for the getLocationsByCounty is:

```
"version": "2018-05-29",
"statements": ["select * from Locations where County = '$ctx.args.County'"]
```

Here is the response resolver:

```
## Raise a GraphQL field error in case of a datasource invocation error
#if($ctx.error)
    $utils.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end

$utils.toJson($utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0])
```

Is this just not allowed in graphQL or is am I doing wrong???

It's worth noting that if I just do this query:

```
select * from Locations where County = 'County'
```

in mySQL, it works exactly as intended.

Comment: Do you need a response resolver? Perhaps something like `$util.toJson($ctx.result)`?  Why does the working response return State:null... is there a ghost record which does not have the state set?

Comment: No, on the database side of things, there isn't a ghost record. In mysql the query returns exactly what I'd expect. 

The resolver is there too. I'm going to include it in my original post.

Comment: What happens if you change the resolver to `$util.toJson($ctx.result)`? Or even just `$ctx.result`